# How do I fill up the remainder of a div with another div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `div` with a `button` inside of it.  The button is a basic `Bootstrap` button.  Here is my code:

```
<div class="generateBtn">
            <button class="btn">Generate Statement</button>
</div>
```

The css looks like this for `generateBtn`:

```
.generateBtn {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
}
```

Here is a pic of what it looks like on the page:
[image]

I want to add a message in the `div` after the `button` and I want the text to be multi-lined and centered.  Here is how I want the `div` to be placed on the page.
[image]

I keep getting my `div` and text directly underneath and my text wrapping wrong.  Can someone give me an idea of how to add this?

Comment: You'll need to include your generated HTML, and probably a diagram of how you want your text displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This working one.  [DEMO at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qodako/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="bottomContainer">
     <div id="buttonDiv">
        <button id="generateButton">Generate Statement</button>
     </div> 

     <div id="requiredDiv">    </div> 
  </div>
  <div id="demoText">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when ...<p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{
  position:relative;
  width:800px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:#E2E3DE;
}

#bottomContainer{
  width:100%;
  height:45px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:#CBCBCB;
  padding:10px 0;
}

#generateButton {
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px; 
}

#buttonDiv{
   margin-left:10px;
   background: #ccc;
   float:left;
}

#requiredDiv{
  width:70%;
  float:left;
  margin-left:200px;
  height:44px;
  top:15%;
  position:absolute;
 background-color:#9EAAB2;
 }

#requiredDiv p{
  top:-15%;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:0.8em;
} 

#demoText{
  display:none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $("#generateButton").click(function(){
      var getdivText= $("#demoText").html();
      $("#requiredDiv").html(getdivText);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gt8Lwj54/)**

you could try nesting the div within a div, and set the parent div with the text properties, and add additional classes to the button to handle the padding and placement...

html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="generateBtn fLeft">
    <button class="btn">Generate Statement</button>
  </div>
  <p> this is the extra copy you want to add to the location with the multi-line set up...style as needed.</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.fLeft { float:left; }

.generateBtn {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
}

.parent {
    background: #ccc;
    overflow:auto;
}

.parent p {
    -add styles for copy here as needed-
}
```